# Misplaced \omit

Tags: tables

The `misplaced \omit` error appeared in the table. I have no idea of the reason why it happens (maybe for multicolumn?). Can you please help me figuring this one out?

```
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{\footnotesize Coefficients of market size and lag dependent when a two-step GMM is employed. \\
Col.(2) includes suspended and withdrawn trials in the dependent}
\label{twstepgmm}
\scalebox{0.6}{ \vspace*{-0.01mm}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(1)}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(2)}} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{log Trials}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{log Trials}}\\ 
\midrule
$\textit{trials}_{t-1}$  &      0.0592   &      0.380\sym{*}      \\
                         &    (0.0426)  &      (0.189)       \\
Log sales                &      0.1208\sym{***} &      -0.533\sym{**}\\
&   (0.159)  & (0.179)
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Year Dummies} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} \\                                            
\midrule  
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Obs.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1664} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1664} \\                                                                                        
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Groups} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{208} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{208}  \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}}
\begin{spacing}{0.1}
\vspace{0.3cm} 
\footnotesize  
{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}
{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}
{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont}
{\Huge }
{\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\tiny Huber-White robust and clustered at ATC-3 level standard errors are in parentheses. (1) is the two-step GMM version of Column (4) Tab.\ref{secstage}, which performed a system one-step GMM. Only the critical coefficients are included. (2) is equal to (1) where also suspended and withdrawn trials are included in the dependent. Only the critical coefficients are included. Both equations are linearized to enable a simple comparison with Column (4) Tab.\ref{secstage}. Thee same results apply if the count of trials is employed as dependent (see \cite{nutarelli})
\end{minipage}}  \\ 
{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}
{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont}  
\end{spacing}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please always provide a small test file that shows the problem. We can not run a fragment. Generally avoid using `\scalebox` on tables (and `vspace` in `\scalebox` can do nothing useful) what is the intention of `{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont}{\Huge }`  which selects fonts of various sizes but all in local groups so has no effect at all?

Comment: also this example seems identical to your previous question where you were also asked to provide a full example

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Year Dummies} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} \\ ` is 4 columns in a 3 column table

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt to impose some order on your code. I've commented out deadwood and/or pointless code, including 5 [!!] `{\fontsize...\selectfont}` directives, and I've replaced `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Year Dummies}` with just `Year Dummies`. (That's the likely source of the error message you report.) I've also replaced `\multicolumn{1}{l}{Obs.}` and `\multicolumn{1}{l}{Groups}` with just `Obs.` and `Groups`, respectively. And, both `\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize ...}` directives should really be `\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize ...}` directives.

BTW, I can see no reason or justification for the `\adjustbox` directive. Employing a `spacing` environment also seems rather unhelpful.

I can't shake the feeling that there are some material errors in the table as well. For instance, if the dependent variable is "log trials", why is the lagged dependent variable denoted by "trials_{t-1}"? Shouldn't it be "log trials_{t-1}"?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\usepackage{%%%graphicx,
    caption,
    %%%setspace,
    dcolumn,
    booktabs}
\newcommand{\mcc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]

%%%\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\caption{%%%\footnotesize 
Coefficients of market size and lag dependent when a two-step GMM is employed. Col.~(2) includes suspended and withdrawn trials in the dependent.}
\label{twstepgmm}

%%%\scalebox{0.6}{ 
%%%\vspace*{-0.01mm}

\begingroup
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l D{.}{.}{2.6} D{.}{.}{2.5} @{}}
\toprule 
& \mcc{(1)}                 & \mcc{(2)} \\
& \mcc{\textit{log Trials}} & \mcc{\textit{log Trials}}\\ 
\midrule
$\textit{trials}_{t-1}$  &   0.0592          &   0.380\sym{*} \\
                         &  (0.0426)         &  (0.189)       \\
Log sales                &   0.1208\sym{***} &  -0.533\sym{**}\\
                         &  (0.159)          &  (0.179) \\
Year dummies             & \mcc{Yes}         & \mcc{Yes} \\
\midrule
Obs.       & \mcc{1664}  & \mcc{1664} \\                                                                     
Groups     & \mcc{208}   & \mcc{208}  \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)} 

%%%\\

\end{tabular}

\endgroup

%%%}
%%%\begin{spacing}{0.1}
%%%\vspace{0.3cm} 
%%%\footnotesize  
%%%{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}
%%%{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}
%%%{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont}
%%%{\Huge }
%%%{
%%%\begin{minipage}{5cm}
%%%\tiny 

\medskip\small
Huber-White robust and clustered at ATC-3 level standard errors are in parentheses. (1)~is the two-step GMM version of Column~(4) Tab.~\ref{secstage}, which performed a system one-step GMM\@. Only the critical coefficients are included. (2)~is equal to (1) where also suspended and withdrawn trials are included in the dependent. Only the critical coefficients are included. Both equations are linearized to enable a simple comparison with Column~(4) Tab.~\ref{secstage}. Thee same results apply if the count of trials is employed as dependent (see \cite{nutarelli})

%%%\end{minipage}
%%%}  
%%%\\ 
%%%{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}
%%%{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont} 
%%%\end{spacing}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```